# How does Keycloak with Android work using SAML protocol?

Tags: android, keycloak, saml

I've successfully created a demo in Android using keycloak openid-connect protocol configuration for SSO. Now I want to do with SAML protocol.

Details I used in openid-connect:

client_id

username

password

grant_type

client_secret

Now, when I changed from openid-connect to SAML inside keycloak dashboard, so client-secreted option got invisible.

So, in android I removed that variable, and also changed in URL from openid-connect to SAML. But getting error that `Page not found`

I seen lot of example, searched and imported github project as well, but wither I'll get demo with openid-connect or I'll get demo without using keyclaok.

I don't understand what else is required.

BTW, I followed this example for openid-connect and it is working as well: https://github.com/thomasdarimont/android-openid-connect/tree/feature/keycloak-oidc-demo

I'll share a bit code:

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args) {
            String authToken = args[0];
            IdTokenResponse response;

            showLog("Requesting ID token.");

            try {
                response = OIDCUtils.requestTokens(Config.tokenServerUrl,
                        Config.redirectUrl,
                        Config.clientId,
                      
                        authToken);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not get response.");
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

            if (isNewAccount) {
                createAccount(response);
            } else {
                setTokens(response);
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Have a look, and there are really less examples on this things. Don't know why!

Answer (score 2):

SAML is primarily for Browser Based Authentication (including Auth-Requests, Redirects, ...). So that's not really suitable for Android apps.

Do you have a good reason to use SAML and not stick to your (already working) OIDC solution?

Comment: Yes, I've a specific reason. Already so many things are configured with SAML form Backend and other side. And I must should use SAML only. This is a specific and Actual requirement, and it cannot change. So only way is, I need to implement in Android anyhow.